# HTML Dropdown tab not opening

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build my first website using the bootstrap template and I cannot get the dropdown button in the nav bar to show anything or open. It will display everything the way I want it, but the "open" function of it isn't working properly for some reason.

Here is what I have in the HTML part:

```
 <li div class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-        
                 toggle="dropdown">General Education <b class="caret"></b></a>


              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="gened.html">Composition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">American Institutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Humanities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Physical Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quantitative Literacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fine Arts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Interdisciplinary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fine Arts</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
```

(I haven't updated all of the target links yet, for now most of them just show as a #)

and for the CSS I have:

```
.dropdown-toggle:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle {
 outline: 0;
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in your code `<li class="dropdown">` try this code 
Your page does not include necessary js files so insert tis line in  section

Script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

HTML

```
<li class="dropdown">
              <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-        
                 toggle="dropdown">General Education <b class="caret"></b></a>


              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="gened.html">Composition</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">American Institutions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Humanities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Physical Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Quantitative Literacy</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fine Arts</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Interdisciplinary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Social Sciences</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fine Arts</a></li>

              </ul>
            </li>
```

Example Markup

```
<!-- start: User Dropdown -->
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a id= "uname" style="color:#fff;text-shadow:none" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> 
    Admin
    <span class="caret"></span>                         
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" ><i class="icon-lock"></i> Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
<!-- end: User Dropdown -->
```

Comment: That still didn't work...every time I click on the link it's like it wants to go to a different page. It  changes from /index.html to /index.html#.

Comment: you clicked non linked element so it adds # to address

Comment: How do I fix that then? The page is located here:

http://brianbolnick.com/Bootstrap.html

Comment: cool thank you. While you are looking at that, The carousel does not change slides either...if you can see whats wrong with that too

Comment: ya problem is you not load th js files kindly see updated ans